# Should I break normalisation rules and add an additional FK

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

In MySQL I have a number of related tables:

- tableA has many rows in tableB
- tableB has many rows in tableC
- tableC has many rows in tableD

I am going to need to traverse from tableA to tableD quite regularly, for example when listing records from tableA along with the count of related records in tableD.  This will lead to cumbersome code, and potential performance bottlenecks.

An alternative would be to create an FK in tableD that refers back to tableA.  Strictly speaking it would be a redundant key, but I think I can manage updates to the values easily enough (to avoid data integrity issues).  I think the performance improvements would be significant and the code would be more readable.

Am I heading in to a world of pain doing this?  Or is it a pattern seen elsewhere?   I plan to label the key so it's clear that it's a convenience only, and not the normative reference.

Answer (score 1):

This not something that you would generally do.  With the right indexes on `tableB` and `tableC`, the performance with the joins should be good enough.

If you find that is not sufficient, then you should try more heroic measures -- such as a duplicated foreign key.  In this case, I see no reason to prematurely optimize the database even before any performance issues arise.